How do I solve Execution failed for task ':device_info_plus:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'. > error: invalid source release: 17 on CircleCI?
This has been happening on my circleci environment. I was able to solve this locally by installing java 17 and using it.
I was somewhat able to deduce what I need to do from this thread, but I'm not sure how to replicate it on CircleCI/Fastlane.
I've tried the following:

Adding this to my build.gradle

        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }

    kotlin {
        jvmToolchain(17)
    }


Adding a step in circle CI to install jdk 17

All of these still get me the error
 Execution failed for task ':device_info_plus:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'. > error: invalid source release: 17

My Fastfile looks like this:
default_platform(:android)

platform :android do
  desc "Submit a new prod release build"
  lane :prod_release do |options|
    build_number = options[:build_number]
    begin
      Dir.chdir "../.." do
        sh("flutter", "clean")
        sh("flutter", "pub", "get")
        sh("flutter", "build", "appbundle", "--build-number=#{build_number}", "--flavor=prod", "-t", "lib/main_prod.dart")
      end
      upload_to_play_store(
        track: 'internal', 
        aab: '../build/app/outputs/bundle/prodRelease/app-prod-release.aab',
        package_name: 'com.appname.members',
      )
      on_success("Successfully released Android pre-release build")
    rescue => exception
      on_error(exception)
      raise
    end
  end

  desc "Submit a new staging release build"
  lane :staging_release do |options|
    build_number = options[:build_number]
    begin
      add_badge(dark: true, glob: "/app/src/main/res/mipmap-*/ic_launcher*.png",)
      Dir.chdir "../.." do
        sh("flutter", "clean")
        sh("flutter", "pub", "get")
        sh("flutter", "build", "appbundle", "--build-number=#{build_number}", "--flavor=staging", "-t", "lib/main_staging.dart")
      end
      upload_to_play_store(
        track: 'internal', 
        aab: '../build/app/outputs/bundle/stagingRelease/app-staging-release.aab', 
        package_name: 'com.appname.members.staging',
      )
      on_success("Successfully released Android staging-release build")
    rescue => exception
      on_error(exception)
      raise
    end
  end

My android/app/build.gradle looks like this:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}


def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}


def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    namespace 'com.appname.members'
    compileSdk flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.appname.members"
        minSdkVersion 28

        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName

        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }

    kotlin {
        jvmToolchain(17)
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
            v1SigningEnabled false
            v2SigningEnabled true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
                    'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "default"

    productFlavors {
        staging {
            dimension "default"
            applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
            manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "Appname Staging", isStaging: true, isProduction: false]
        }
        prod {
            dimension "default"
            applicationIdSuffix ""
            manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "Appname", isStaging: false, isProduction: true]
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.9.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1'
    implementation 'com.polidea.rxandroidble2:rxandroidble:1.11.1'

    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0"

    implementation 'androidx.window:window:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0'
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'
}

and my circle ci config:
version: "2.1"
orbs:
  flutter: circleci/flutter@2.0.2
  android: circleci/android@2.5.0

parameters:
  manual-staging-run:
    type: boolean
    default: false

workflows:
  build:
    jobs:
      - lint_and_test:
          filters:
            branches:
              ignore:
                - staging
                - main
  deploy_staging:
    jobs:
      - lint_and_test:
          filters:
            branches:
              only: staging
      - deploy_staging_android:
          requires:
            - lint_and_test
  deploy_prod:
    jobs:
      - lint_and_test:
          filters:
            branches:
              only: main
      - deploy_prod_android:
          requires:
            - lint_and_test
  manual_deploy_staging:
    when: << pipeline.parameters.manual-staging-run >>
    jobs:
      - lint_and_test
      - deploy_staging_android:
          requires:
            - lint_and_test

commands:
  setup_env:
    steps:
      - checkout
      - flutter/install_sdk_and_pub:
          version: 3.19.5
      - run:
          name: Install Zoom SDK
          command: flutter pub run zoom:unzip_zoom_sdk
  run_fastlane:
    parameters:
      fastlane_lane:
        default: "staging_release"
        type: string
      platform:
        default: ""
        type: string
    steps:
      - run:
          no_output_timeout: 30m
          name: Fastlane
          command: bundle exec fastlane <<parameters.fastlane_lane>> build_number:$CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM
          working_directory: <<parameters.platform>>
  build_android:
    parameters:
      flavor:
        default: staging
        type: string
      output_dir:
        default: output
        type: string
    steps:
      - setup_env
      - flutter/install_android_gradle_dependencies
      - flutter/install_android_gem
      - run: echo "$PLAY_STORE_UPLOAD_KEY" | base64 --decode > android/appname-health-keystore
      - run: echo "$PLAY_STORE_UPLOAD_KEY_INFO" | base64 --decode > android/key.properties
      - run: echo "$SUPPLY_JSON_KEY_DATA" > android/play-store-credentials.json
      - run_fastlane:
          fastlane_lane: <<parameters.flavor>>_release
          platform: android
      # - run_fastlane:
      #      fastlane_lane: <<parameters.flavor>>_apk
      #      platform: android
      - store_artifacts:
          path: <<parameters.output_dir>>
          destination: outputs

jobs:
  deploy_staging_android:
    description: Deploy Staging build to internal testers in Play Store
    executor:
      name: android/android-machine
      tag: 2023.02.1
    steps:
      - build_android:
          flavor: staging
          output_dir: android/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-staging-release.apk

  deploy_prod_android:
    description: Deploy Prod build to internal testers in Play Store
    executor:
      name: android/android-machine
      tag: 2023.02.1
    steps:
      - build_android:
          flavor: prod
          output_dir: android/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-prod-release.apk

  lint_and_test:
    description: Run flutter analyze and Unit Tests
    docker:
      - image: "ghcr.io/cirruslabs/flutter:3.19.5"
    steps:
      - checkout
      - flutter/install_pub
      - run: echo 'export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"' >> $BASH_ENV
      - run:
          name: Install junitreport
          shell: "/bin/bash --login -eo pipefail"
          command: dart pub global activate junitreport
      - run: mkdir test-results
      - run:
          name: Run flutter analysis
          command: flutter analyze
      - run:
          name: Run Unit Test
          command: flutter test --machine | tojunit -o test-results/unit-test-report.xml
      - store_test_results:
          path: test-results



I am having the same issue on github actions and codemagic. Have you solved it?
